# Can we predict time by using Machine Learning?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, large-data, supervised-learning

I am struggling with a Use Case. In that use case I have to predict the time(hour and minute) to reach user. I am unable to find which ML Algo to solve this use case.
Can any one help to solve.
Thanks

Comment: Predicting hour and minute sounds hard, but you can alway predict [POSIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (number of seconds from some starting point) or something similar, then you are just predicting values on real line.

Comment: Hi Tim, I applied Regression and SVR and both model output between 9 to 13(hour) i.e non normally distributed output

Answer (score 2):

You can model time $T$ on the positive real line. In your case ($T=$waiting time from the moment you start trying to reach the user), it is common to model it with an exponential distribution. You can use a [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) with an exponential distribution.